# Android Color Detection

Tags: android

I want to make this program can detect blue and yellow shown on the frame at the same time

but i don't know the next step..

i got this code from

http://berenoune.blogspot.com/2012/10/opencv-android-java-color-detection.html

here is the code...

**ColorDetection**

```
    ColorDetection.java (com.duckie.color)
/*
 * berenoune
 * http://berenoune.blogspot.com/
 * 10/27/X2
 * 
 */

package com.duckie.color;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class ColorDetection {

private static Mat mSrc;

public static void cvt_YUVtoRGBtoHSV(Mat src, Mat dst){
mSrc = new Mat();
src.copyTo(mSrc); 
Imgproc.cvtColor(mSrc,dst,Imgproc.COLOR_YUV420sp2RGB);
Imgproc.cvtColor(dst,dst, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);
}

public static void getBlueMat(Mat src, Mat dst){
Core.inRange(src, new Scalar(100, 100, 100), new Scalar(120, 255, 255), dst);
}

public static void getYellowMat(Mat src, Mat dst){
Core.inRange(src, new Scalar(20, 100, 100), new Scalar(30, 255, 255), dst);
}

public static void detectSingleBlob(Mat src, Mat image, String text, Mat dst){
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>(); //vector<vector<Point> > contours;
Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
src.copyTo(dst);

Imgproc.findContours(image, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

int k = getBiggestContourIndex(contours);
Rect boundRect = setContourRect(contours, k);

Point center = new Point();
getCenterPoint(boundRect.tl(), boundRect.br(), center);
Core.rectangle(dst, boundRect.tl(), boundRect.br(), new Scalar(255, 255, 0), 2, 8, 0 );

Core.putText(dst, text, boundRect.tl(), 0/*font*/, 1, new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 3);
}

public static void getCenterPoint(Point tl, Point br, Point dst){
dst.x = (tl.x + br.x)/2;
dst.y = (tl.y + br.y)/2;
}

public static int getBiggestContourIndex(List<MatOfPoint> contours){
double maxArea = 0;
Iterator<MatOfPoint> each = contours.iterator();
int j = 0;
int k = -1;
while (each.hasNext())
{
MatOfPoint wrapper = each.next();
double area = Imgproc.contourArea(wrapper);
if (area > maxArea){
maxArea = area;
k = j;
}
j++;
}
return k;
}

public static Rect setContourRect(List<MatOfPoint> contours,int k){
Rect boundRect = new Rect();
Iterator<MatOfPoint> each = contours.iterator();
int j = 0;
while (each.hasNext()){
MatOfPoint wrapper = each.next();
if (j==k){
return Imgproc.boundingRect( wrapper );
}
j++;
}
return boundRect;
}
}
```